# Displaying attributes from another model using CGRIDVIEW

Tags: php, database, gridview, yii, relation

I have 2 tables/models:

**Tmp1**

- Header
- QuestionText

**Tmp2**

- Header
- Part
- OutOf

I'm trying to display the columns: *Header, QuestionText, Part, OutOf*
in a single CGRIDVIEW.

**In Tmp1 model:**

```
public function relations()  
{  
  return array(  
               'tmp2s' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Tmp2', 'Header'),  
              );  
}
```

**In Tmp2 Model:**

```
public function relations()
{  
    return array(  
        'header' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Tmp1', 'Header'),  
    );  
}
```

**Controller:**

```
 public function actionReviewAll()  
    {  
        $tmp1 = new Tmp1('search');  
                $tmp1->unsetAttributes();  

        if(isset($_GET['Tmp1'])){  
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Tmp1'];  
        }  

        $this->render('ReviewAll',array(  
                'tmp1'=>$tmp1,  
        ));  
    }
```

**View:**

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'tmp-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$tmp1->search(),
    'filter'=>$tmp1,
    'columns'=>array(
        'Header',
        'QuestionText',
        array(
            'name' => 'tmp2.OutOf',
            'value' => '$data->tmp2[0].OutOf',
            'type' => 'raw'
        ),

    ),

)); ?>
```

**Error:**

> Property "Tmp1.tmp2" is not defined.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a sintax error:

Tmp1.tmp2 = Tmp1.tmp2s

The relation alias is with 's'. "tmp2s".

```
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'tmp-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$tmp1->search(),
    'filter'=>$tmp1,
    'columns'=>array(
        'Header',
        'QuestionText',
        'tmp2s.Part',
        'tmp2s.OutOf',
    ),

)); ?>
```

But you are trying to show a 'self::HAS_MANY' relationship, you can't show that on a normal CGridView widget...

Comment: Should have been HAS_ONE. Working now! Thanks for the help

Comment: Perfeect! the relation it's the most important ^^

Answer (score 0):

Your code *probably* works (I haven't tried it), but not in cases where your tmp1 model has no tmp2's. You must make sure there is a tmp2 before accessing it:

```
'value' => 'isset($data->tmp2) ? $data->tmp2[0].OutOf : Null',
```

You can also pass a function($data,$row) to value to make it look less messy. (Yes, that's important to me.)

Comment: This fixes the error. The grid displays the column now, but apparently none of the tmp1 have tmp2's; they are all defaulted to null. Any idea why this is? Maybe there's something wrong with the relation?